# An exception occurred using lua_redis: MOVED 10743

Tags: nginx, redis, lua

when I use redis by lua, I can't get a key from redis. An exception occurred. And you can see the detail:
this is my lua code:

```lua
local ip_list,err = red:get("eask:gray:ips");
if not ip_list then
    ngx.log(ngx.INFO,"redis ","failed to get,"..err.." ")
end
ngx.log(ngx.INFO,"=====ip_list=====",ip_list)
```

and the error log:

```
[lua] gray_redis.lua:53: redis failed to get,MOVED 10743 133.*.*.5:16388
[lua] gray_redis.lua:58: =====ip_list=====false,
```

Answer (score 1):

I seem to understand, I use redis cluster，the key not in this node